# zipalign tool was not found in the sdk. try it manually

Tags: android, sdk

Updated to new ADT23 and SDK23-->Installed all the recent build tool as well as 20(also tried installing all of them)--> moved the zipalign folder under tools and also tried under platform-tools..After trying everything. I uninstalled and reinstalled. Still i am getting an error. Please help. I need to post my app soon.

Comment: I figured it out. Drove me crazy.Make sure after downloading the new sdk, you have to go to Eclipse preference and change the path for sdk. Hope this helps someone else

Comment: I need to change of path of the sdk to what ? Because it's still the same path

Comment: i had to point out to the path where i had my new sdk file. It will still trying to look for the old one which wasn't there since i upgraded the sdk

Answer (score 3):

Every Sdk that you download have zipalign inside. 
You should only copy it from the bundle.

For example if you have 19.1, you can find zipalign in this path:

*/pathToYourSdx/sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/*

Copy it to:
*/pathToYourSdx/sdk/tools and gradle will be happy. Infact Gradle try to find zipalign.exe in tools folder.*

Hope this help,

Comment: instead of copying it in tools folder just use the one which is in build-tools :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, zipalign.exe wasn't in the tool folder after updating to latest sdk.
Luckily, I had saved on another hard drive a previous configuration in which there was the zipalign.exe file. I copied it and pasted in the tools folder then I followed the normal procedure to zipalign the apk and it worked.

Comment: Instead of copying it in tools folder just use the one which is in build-tools :)